# Can I change what types of files are considered "potentially unsafe content" in Internet Explorer?

Tags: security, pdf, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

## Unsafe File Types - Editable?

In Internet Explorer's security zone settings, one of the options controls whether IE prompts you before downloading "potentially unsafe content" from a web site.  By default, this is enabled on the **Medium** setting and higher.  I understand how to modify this behavior, but what I want to know is *how can I find and modify which file types are classified as unsafe content?*

## New behavior for PDFs?

The reason I ask is that I suspect PDFs have been added to the list of unsafe files recently.  I am 90% certain that until the last month or so, when I downloaded PDFs from a trusted site, it never asked me if I wanted to open or save, but now it does.  As a test, if I change the trusted sites security level to **Medium-low**, it opens without prompting.  In my particular situation, I would rather remove PDFs from the list of potentially unsafe to the list of safe files rather than lower my security settings for all potentially unsafe file types.

## Screenshots

[image: IE security zone settings screenshot] [image: IE detailed zone settings screenshot - prompt when Launching Applications and Unsafe files]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I'm using 32-bit IE 11 on Windows 7 Pro, 64-bit OS.  I'll see if I can get my hands on an older unpatched machine for comparison.